# "Flexible" network configuration for fixed and autonegotiation

Tags: networking, duplex

I have a device that collect data and implement a web server to show them. This should connect to a switch to be visible in the network. My problem is that it must be installed in different scenarios, I mean, sometimes the switch is configured for network autonegotiation (speed and duplex), in other cases the switch is configured in fixed mode (say 100M full duplex).
Is there a way/best practice to configure my device so that it can work in both cases? One idea could be to create a web page from where the user can select the connection mode, but, if a wrong setting is selected, I lost the connection to the device.

Comment: Note that for gigabit and faster connections, autonegotiation is ***required***.  Anyone who says otherwise doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: For my case, maximum speed is 100M